# FileInfo.MoveTo() vs File.Move()

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

Is there any difference between these two methods of moving a file?

```
System.IO.FileInfo f = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"c:\foo.txt");
f.MoveTo(@"c:\bar.txt");

//vs

System.IO.File.Move(@"c:\foo.txt", @"c:\bar.txt");
```

Comment: What is the question? They appear to be two different methods to reach the same API. Are you looking for looped performance or best practices or ???

Comment: I was just curious why there were two methods that appear to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Well hopefully the snippets below show you how they differ? Also, if you're not using the (currently free) Reflector product from Red Gate, you should.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. And yes I have Reflector. I just never think to use it on the actual framework only when I'm trying to reverse engineer some other 3rd party code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take a look at "Remarks" section in this MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akth6b1k.aspx :

> If you are going to reuse an object several times, consider using the instance method of `FileInfo` instead of the corresponding static methods of the `File` class, because a security check will not always be necessary.

I think this difference is most significant between `File` (`Directory`) and `FileInfo` (`DirectoryInfo`) classes.

Update: The same explanation in similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324808/380123

Answer (score 15):

An important difference is that `FileInfo.MoveTo()` will update the **filepath** of the `FileInfo` object to the destination path. This is obviously not the case of `File.Move()` since it only uses strings as input.

Comment: This one cost me quite some time! Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 14):

Via RedGate Reflector:

File.Move()

```
public static void Move(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)
{
    if ((sourceFileName == null) || (destFileName == null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException((sourceFileName == null) ? "sourceFileName" : "destFileName", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentNull_FileName"));
    }
    if ((sourceFileName.Length == 0) || (destFileName.Length == 0))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_EmptyFileName"), (sourceFileName.Length == 0) ? "sourceFileName" : "destFileName");
    }
    string fullPathInternal = Path.GetFullPathInternal(sourceFileName);
    new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write | FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, new string[] { fullPathInternal }, false, false).Demand();
    string dst = Path.GetFullPathInternal(destFileName);
    new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, new string[] { dst }, false, false).Demand();
    if (!InternalExists(fullPathInternal))
    {
        __Error.WinIOError(2, fullPathInternal);
    }
    if (!Win32Native.MoveFile(fullPathInternal, dst))
    {
        __Error.WinIOError();
    }
}
```

and FileInfo.MoveTo()

```
public void MoveTo(string destFileName)
{
    if (destFileName == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("destFileName");
    }
    if (destFileName.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_EmptyFileName"), "destFileName");
    }
    new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write | FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, new string[] { base.FullPath }, false, false).Demand();
    string fullPathInternal = Path.GetFullPathInternal(destFileName);
    new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, new string[] { fullPathInternal }, false, false).Demand();
    if (!Win32Native.MoveFile(base.FullPath, fullPathInternal))
    {
        __Error.WinIOError();
    }
    base.FullPath = fullPathInternal;
    base.OriginalPath = destFileName;
    this._name = Path.GetFileName(fullPathInternal);
    base._dataInitialised = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only significant difference I can see is `File.Move` is static and `FileInfo.MoveTo` is not.
Apart from that they run approximately the same code.

Comment: Yeah I agree; and FileInfo inherits FileSystemInfo versus File just inherits Object. FileSystemInfo apparently only gives Marshalling, so I would guess that FileInfo is more Managed Friendly.