# Is FileInfo.Exists/Copy faster than File?

Tags: c#, file, io, copy, exists

As the title says is which one of the scenarios below is faster?

```
        // Using FileInfo
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\Test.txt");

        if (file.Exists)
            file.CopyTo(@"C:\TestCopy.txt");

        // Using File
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Test.txt"))
            File.Copy(@"C:\Test.txt", @"C:\TestCopy.txt");
```

I know the FileInfo is easier for the eye to read, but is one method faster than the other?

Comment: Have you tried to write a benchmark for your case?

Comment: write small test and share the result

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324788/what-is-the-difference-between-file-and-fileinfo-in-c . YMMV, and will depend on your exact use case, so doing a benchmark as suggested by others is probably the best way to find out.

Comment: If I were to _guess_ I'd say the first one is marginally faster.  It's likely that the _exact_ same API operations are being performed internally, but in the second case one of them is being performed twice.

Comment: You won't be able to tell them apart. Use whichever you like best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difference is that FileInfo cache information: file existing check is executed once.
Then, if you check Exists property and THEN create file, new call to Exists property always will return false.

Comment: This is true, but note that the file existance check is lazily executed.

Comment: @MatthewWatson How so? Further explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: @SepehrM I mean that an internal bool field for `FileInfo.Exists` isn't initialised by the `FileInfo` constructor. Instead, it is initialised when you first call `FileInfo.Exists`. (You can see this by inspecting the implementation using Reflector or similar.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks, I wasn't familiar with the term "Lazy Evaluation/Execution"!