# C# results FALSE at `File.Exists` even if the file EXISTS

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

As title says I don't know what's wrong with my code but `if (File.Exists)` give negative result even if the file is there.

Below is my code

```
if (File.Exists(ZFileConfig.FileName.Replace(".xml", "_abc.xml")))
```

Here, `ZFileConfig.FileName` is `E:\\Application\\Application\\bin\\Debug\\resources\\FirstFile.xml`

And amazingly `ZFileConfig.FileName.Replace(".xml", "_abc.xml")` gives me `E:\\Application\\Application\\bin\\Debug\\resources\\FirstFile_abc.xml` that is what is needed. EVENTHOUGH `IF` falied to return TRUE.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you are saying that `File.Exists` says that the file doesn't exist, even if it does? Are you SURE that the file 'FirstFile_abs.xml' exists? Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: What is the return value of ZFileConfig.FileName.Replace()? Start there. You may be making an assumption about what is actually returned.

Comment: Does your application have permissions to access the directory?

Comment: You shouldn't use `File.Exists` anyway.  Even if it returns true now, the file could be deleted before you open it.  Just try to open and handle the exception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like your file is actually named `abc_RotateFlip.xml.xml`.

I can't imagine why any programmer would ever allow hidden file extensions, but your Excel file shows that they are indeed hidden.  Turn that off!  Choose to know what's going on inside your computer!

[image]

You can also use this registry script to change that setting;

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"HideFileExt"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: I too think so. But I want to ask you one thing. Here this `.xml` file is made from DataSet.WriteToXml() where WriteToXml() is UDF to make a `.xml` file. I am making two files `dsLabelFileConfig.WriteXml(info.Directory + @"\" + info.Name + ".xml");` and `dsRotateFlip.WriteXml(info.Name.Replace(".xml" , "_RotateFlip.xml"));`. But first is nicely made. Why second makes problems.?

Comment: @DhavalR: If the replace is doing something, then `info.Name` already ends in `.xml`.  And then `info.Name + ".xml"` ends in `.xml.xml`

Comment: `dsLabelFileConfig` is good. But `dsRotateFlip` is making problem.

Comment: @DhavalR: I don't know because I don't have all your code.  Maybe another `.xml` is added inside `WriteXML`.  Maybe you or a coworker saw the file in Explorer without .xml on the end, because it was hidden, and added it.  Surely you can debug through the file creation and see if it uses the wrong name.

Answer (score 3):

Please check with `FileInfo` :

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"_abc.xml");
bool isExists = fi.Exists;
```

> [Generally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324788/what-is-the-difference-between-file-and-fileinfo-in-c) if you are performing a single operation on a file, use the File class. If you are performing multiple operations on the same file, use FileInfo.
>
> The reason to do it this way is because of the security checking done when accessing a file. When you create an instance of FileInfo, the check is only performed once. However, each time you use a static File method the check is performed.

Comment: +1 Good call. It's also good practice to clarify your code when encountering seemingly strange behavior where each constituent operation is a separate line of code and assignment to a temp variable. It gets verbose but allows you to debug each call individually rather than two or more at once that are folded into a single line of code.

Comment: Hm, can you explain it? How can a chek for "_abc.xml" solve his problem? and why `fi.Exist` is better then `File.Exists`?

Comment: @Shahrooz jefri: Tried that too. But still `false`.

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ thanks, but what about "_abc.xml" part? His file should be "somethingold_abc.xml"

Comment: I tried both the ways using `FileInfo` and `File Class`. But what is happening.?