# How to clear browser cache programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to clear the firefox 8 browser cache using programmatically. I am developing as a site using asp.net, I need to clear the browser cache for the security reason. I tried many ways to clear the cache but none seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can do it But........

You can't clear a browser's history via code because of browsers security reasons.

But you can **delete all the files and folders under browsers "cache" directory using
file operation**.

eg. Mozilla's default cache location(hidden) is 
"..AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\2nfq77n2.default\Cache"

[How to delete all files and folders in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288718/how-to-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory)
try it!

Comment: can't delete this directory,because using another process or program.how to solve it..

Comment: ok you can,t delete it, but you can clear the cache by deleting subdir of cache.

Comment: deleting subdirectory of cache is fine.but cache is not clear.     Note :once firefox is closed all the files are deleted,otherwise i can't delete it......Any idea?

Comment: You mean when Firefox is running , it will not allow to delete sub-directories, But I tried it and it will even works fine while Firefox is running. May be your requirement is someway different.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think this would be possible due to security reasons .
At max you can set HTTP header to tell the browser not to  chache your pages like this :

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Comment: I think this is best decision when you are controlling the cache of your website.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to clear browser's cache programmatically, however you can stop caching from your application.

Below code will help you for disabling caching and clears existing cache from your application:

```
public static void DisablePageCaching()
{
    //Used for disabling page caching
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code (C#):

```
public static void DeleteFirefoxCache()
    {
        string profilesPath = @"Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles";
        string localProfiles = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), profilesPath);
        string roamingProfiles = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), profilesPath);

        if (Directory.Exists(localProfiles))
        {
            var profiles = Directory.GetDirectories(localProfiles).OfType<string>().ToList();
            profiles.RemoveAll(prfl => prfl.ToLowerInvariant().EndsWith("geolocation")); // do not delete this profile.

            profiles.ForEach(delegate(string path) 
            {                    
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>();

                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    if (!Common.IsFileLocked(new FileInfo(file)))
                        File.Delete(file);
                }            
            });
        }

        if (Directory.Exists(roamingProfiles))
        {
            var profiles = Directory.GetDirectories(roamingProfiles).OfType<string>().ToList();

            profiles.RemoveAll(prfl => prfl.ToLowerInvariant().EndsWith("geolocation")); // do not delete this profile.
            profiles.ForEach(delegate(string path)
            {
                var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OfType<string>().ToList();
                dirs.ForEach(delegate(string dir) 
                {
                    var files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>();

                    foreach (string file in files)
                    {
                        if (!Common.IsFileLocked(new FileInfo(file)))
                            File.Delete(file);
                    }   
                });

                var files0 = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).OfType<string>().ToList();
                files0.ForEach(delegate(string file) 
                {
                    if (!Common.IsFileLocked(new FileInfo(file)))
                        File.Delete(file);
                });
            });
        }                    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
string UserProfile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
            try
            {
                string id = string.Empty;
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines($@"{UserProfile}\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini");
                foreach (var line in lines)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("Path=Profiles/"))
                    {
                        var text = line.Replace("Path=Profiles/", "");
                        id = text.Trim();
                    }
                }
                Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles($@"{UserProfile}\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\{id}\cache2\entries"), File.Delete);
            }
            catch { }
```

Answer (score -1):

In asp.net/ c# you can trigger this.

```
string cacheKey = "TestCache";

//Add cache
   Cache.Add(cacheKey, "Cache content", null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), 
TimeSpan.Zero, CacheItemPriority.High, null);

Cache.Remove(cacheKey); //C# clear cache
```