# Delete all items from browser cache in C#

Tags: c#, caching, browser-cache

I'm trying to delete all cache of a browser, however it doesn't get deleted. 
Here is the code where i set expire some cookies that i know. what about cache, any suggestions?

```
string[] cookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
foreach (string cookie in cookies)
{
   Response.Cookies[cookie].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
}
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't. That would open a very big security issue. If you want to make sure that the browser gets some content from your server instead of fetching from the client's cache, then serve with a different query string every time.

Comment: You can't. See [How to clear browser cache programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306839/how-to-clear-browser-cache-programatically).