# Clear css and javascript browser cache

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc

How can I clear JavaScript and CSS cache in ASP MVC without Clear browser > history?

Comment: From javascript you can use location.reload(true); which forces a load from the server, but it refreshes the page, or you can take a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306839/how-to-clear-browser-cache-programatically which is asp.net related.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct and easy of doing so. Closest I can think of would be is to use:

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

It will ignore the current cached items and will try fetching the new ones.

The better approach I can think of is about using a version number to the path or filename, like PATH?v=VersionNumber