# How do I delete the entire folder/ directory?

Tags: c#, file, directory, delete-file

I want to delete the entire folder or directory along with files and folders contained in it. How can I implement in C#?

Comment: You tagged asp.net. Then Delete on client-side or server-side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using

```
Directory.Delete(dir_path, true);
```

Check [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx)

Comment: @Default: thanks, I didn't see I had italian page (but "as original", so in English !!)

Answer (score 1):

Since it is tagges c# I assume the directory is at server side.Refer this link

[How to delete all files and folders in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288718/how-to-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 1):

```
var dInfo = new DirectoryInfo("your_path_to_dir");
dInfo.Delete(true);
```

The true parameter in the Delete method is Recursive = true.
This tells the method to delete the current folder and everything inside it.
Files and folders.

Comment: Path is to be mentioned along with the directory name?

Comment: @coder311: `Path` is the directory full path, the one I called `dir_path`

Comment: Your code works, but getting `DirectoryInfo` just to delete a folder is cpu-wasting ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. And it depends, if he had performed some other action before delete. May be he needd to check some conditions before that...