# How to delete all files from a specific folder?

Tags: c#, .net

I save files in a specific folder at run time. After some time, I want to delete them programmatically. How do I delete all files from a specific folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to delete all files and folders in a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288718/how-to-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
File.Delete(filePath);
```

Or in a single line:

```
Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\"), File.Delete);
```

Comment: An even shorter syntax using a method group:  `Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\"), File.Delete);`

Comment: VB: Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(folderPath), Sub(x) File.Delete(x))

Comment: no need to add parameters to.File.Delete?!

Comment: The Path is a parameter

Comment: i am using single line code Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\"), File.Delete); but when my directory is empty then its provide errors so how can check if there is file or not before this line of code..

Comment: Directory.GetFiles(path).Length > 0

Comment: double bonus for the Array.ForEach

Answer (score 15):

You can do it via [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.delete.aspx) or [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c66e2tts.aspx):

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("TempDir");
di.Delete(true);
```

And then recreate the directory

Comment: +1, this is probably the easiest way if you just want to trash the directory entirely, saves looping over every single file.

Comment: Ok, but if this directory has specific user's permissions, you'll loose them.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti: true. But I suspect the user created this temp directory himself.

Comment: This should be the best answer!

Answer (score 9):

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo myDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(myDirPath);

foreach (FileInfo file in myDirInfo.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete(); 
}
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in myDirInfo.GetDirectories())
{
    dir.Delete(true); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the following namespace,

```
using System.IO;
```

and use the `Directory` class to reach on the specific folder:

```
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(@"your directory path");
foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
    File.Delete(fileName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\directory\"))
  File.Delete(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
Directory directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
List<FileInfo> fileInfos = directory.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
foreach (FileInfo f in fileInfos)
    File.Delete(f.FullName);
```