# Not able to delete folder using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, delete-file

I want to delete all files from the folder if the *specified directory* exist. I tried with below code, but it is giving me error as

> Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Username\VSATFINAL_353\VSATTSSRSurvey\NESSPATH\VSAT\SignedDoc\I-KA-CTPR-ENB-9016C3.pdf'.

I tried with below code but it is not working.

```
protected void delete_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strServerFolder = "";            
        string strSapID = EncryptDecrypt.Decrypt(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["SapId"]));
        string strCandidateId = EncryptDecrypt.Decrypt(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["CandidateId"]));


        strServerFolder = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VSATSharedPath"].ToString() + strSAPCandidate + @"\" + "SignedDoc" + @"\");

        string strFilePath = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VSATSharedPath"].ToString() + strSAPCandidate + @"\" + "SignedDoc" + @"\" + strSapID + "_" + strCandidateId + ".pdf" + @"\");

        if (!Directory.Exists(strServerFolder))
        {
            Directory.Delete(strFilePath);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looking at your code, you are trying to delete a file path using `Directory.Delete` which wont work.

Comment: @Valeklosse: So how could I delete the file ?

Comment: Have you tried File.Delete(path)? And not sure if it's a typo, but as the code stands now you try to remove something if the directory does NOT exist

Comment: @VVVV `File.Delete` should do the trick, there is also a `File.Exists` method which is probably a good idea to use before deleting the file.

Comment: @AssaultingCuccos: No, let me try that

Comment: @AssaultingCuccos: not working getting error as `Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Username\VSATFINAL_353\VSATTSSRSurvey\NESSPATH\VSAT\I-DL-DLHI-ENB-3305C2\SignedDoc\'.`

Comment: @AssaultingCuccos: so what is the correct way of deleting the files ?? u can suggest me and I will change it accordingly

Comment: Using `Directory/File.Exists` does not mean you can skip handling the exception.. some one could delete the file between your check and your actual call to `.Delete`..

Comment: @Peter: Kindly suggest me the standard way of deleting it. any link will also do

Comment: @VVVV Have you checked this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297024/how-to-delete-all-files-from-a-specific-folder? There are many ways to delete files but the directory path should be valid one to do it.

Comment: @VVVV look at my answer below.

Comment: Something I tried: `if (Directory.Exists(strServerFolder) && Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetFolder, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any() == true) { Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(targetFolder), File.Delete) }`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto: yes its working but when I again upload the file, it doesn't uploads the file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete all files and folders in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288718/how-to-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deleting a directory instead of a file:

```
    if (!Directory.Exists(strServerFolder))
    {
        Directory.Delete(strFilePath);
    }
```

try

```
    if (!File.Exists(strServerFolder))
    {
        File.Delete(strFilePath);
    }
```

Comment: thanks peter, one more thing here. I want to check if file other `strServerFolder` is uploaded then it should stop it. How to check that

Answer (score 1):

The documentation contains all the exceptions that can be thrown https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1

```
try
{
    File.Delete(strFilePath);
}
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
{
    //File not found
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    //File in use
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
{
    //Access denied
}
```

Comment: sorry peter, went for meeting. I tried with your code. But getting error as `{"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.\r\n"}`

Comment: i tried with `strServerFolder` but I am getting exception as `Access to the path 'D:\Username\VSATFINAL_353\VSATTSSRSurvey\NESSPATH\VSAT\I-TN-ARKM-ENB-0014_C1\SignedDoc' is denied.`

Comment: @VVVV Then that means that the user that is running the code does not have access to the specified file or directory. try running the code as a different user or give the current user access to the file/directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to delete file, you should use `File.Delete` method. And, you should check if file exists, not directory. If directory doesn't exist, you will get `false` when checking file, and more importantly, directory might exist but file may still missing and you will not be able to delete it.
So, you should have:

```
if (File.Exists(strFilePath))
{
    File.Delete(strFilePath);
}
```

Additionally, you are trying to delete if directory **doesn't** exist which is impossible by definition and will always throw exception when it happens that there is no directory (and if it is there, it will be ignored).