# Delete Files in Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I delete the files in a folder in a directory via a button click?

This is the currant method I have tried.

```
    protected void BtnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/Notes/"), File.Delete)
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working so any alternative would be appreciated

Comment: Please read [ask]. "Doesn't seem to be working" is not a proper problem description.

Comment: Please take a look on [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288718/how-to-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory)! You can do it like various methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288718/how-to-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory) should provide you with plenty of information.

Code snippet from there:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("YourPath");

foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete(); 
}
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
{
    dir.Delete(true); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To delete files in a folder use this code (can put it inside your event handler):

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("YourPath");

foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("/Notes/");

foreach (var file in info.GetFiles())
 file.Delete();
```