# Delete files but not folder C#

Tags: c#, file

I have a code to delete folder and all files in it. I need to delete only files inside folder and not folder itself folder "1" for example must remain)... How can this be done using this code?

```
public class Deletefolder
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

           var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\d\wid\1");
            dir.Attributes = dir.Attributes & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

                dir.Delete(true);

            }

        }
```

Comment: If you're not going to delete the folder, I'd rename your class to "EmptyFolder" or something similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete all files and folders in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288718/how-to-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 12):

You could use following code:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("YourPath");

foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete(); 
}
```

Directly 'stolen' from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1288747/1661209

I think this question is almost an exact duplicate of that one.