# How to delete all folders except "Games" Folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to delete all folders except "Games" Folder
I Have This Script Without Except

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(a);
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
{
dir.Delete(true);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "folder name"? Do you mean how to delete content of all folders but keep the folders themselves?

Comment: @GiladGreen i mean delete all folders except "Games" Folder

Comment: Do you want it recursively? Or just in that given `a` path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288718/how-to-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory Hope this will help you

Comment: @karthikeyan i know how to delete all folders i just need how to delete all folders except "games" folder

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(a);

foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories().Where( x=> x.Name != "Games"))
{
    dir.Delete(true);
}
```